# OpenGL, model matrix as no rotation/translation/scale

Tags: opengl, matrix, transform

I am playing with opnegl (the old one, sorry for the modern opengl guys), and I'm trying to understand the matrixes and replace `glRotatef`, `glTranslatef` etc with `glLoadMatrixf`.

I don't understand how to set a matrix with no rotation, no translation, no scale. I thought I could use an identity matrix but it doesn't work.

I'd like to have a matrix such that writing:

```
glPushMatrix();
{
    drawMyCube();
}
glPopMatrix();
```

is the equivalent to writing:

```
glPushMatrix();
{
    glLoadMatrixf( myCubeTransform.getTranspose() );
    drawMyCube();
}
glPopMatrix();
```

If I have something like:

```
/* 1: */ // glLoadMatrixf( myCubeTransform.getTranspose() );
/* 2: */ // glLoadIdentity();
```

In the first place I thought to use myCubeTranform Matrix4 class (and I'm using a row-major order matrix class so I have to getTranspose() to match opengl column-major order) but it doesn't work, so I used `glLoadIdentity` to be sure to does not make mess with my Matrix4 class (some bug in matrix code?) and.. it doesn't work either.

So my question: how to set a transform matrix with no translation, no rotation, no scale?

With "does not work" I mean that my cube is not in the origin (where I want it to be). Actually, I don't see it at all (prob. it is drawn outside the view frustum?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*glLoadMatrix* will replace what's on top of the matrix stack. Which means, that it will nil your view setup, that you probably did before. You have to choices: Either implement the view part yourself as well and pre-multiply that on the model transformation. Or (for learning purposes) use *glMultMatrix* instead of where you have *glLoadMatrix* right now.

Comment: so I can use glLoadMatrix only if I have all the stack of the transformation (or if it is the first one).. otherways I have to use glMultMatrix.. ok. And in the perspective of learning the modern gl, what is the best?

Comment: Just to get this out of the way: OpenGL matrix stack != transformation hierachy stack. Although they're usually used in a way, that the one reflects the other. Anyway, if you want to go for modern OpenGL you'd use a library like GLM, Eigen or linmath.h to build a compound of transformations into a matrix. Everytime the transformation heirachy branches you make a copy. The final matrix you pass as a uniform.